# Reshape data table from wide to long with transpose

Tags: r, tidyr, reshape, melt

I have a dataset (Sample_pH):

```
Head(Sample_pH)

Mill   Acid `1_day`          `3_days` `1_week` `2_weeks` `4_weeks` `2_months` `3_months` `6-7_months`
  <chr> <dbl> <chr>               <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>       
1 Gävle  0    10.5                12.0     10.9      10.7      10.6       10.1       10    9.81        
2 Gävle  0.5  8.7899999999999~    10        9.29      9.08      9.39       9.13       9.14 8.86        
3 Gävle  0.75 8.0500000000000~     8.95     8.33      8.26      8.24       8.22       8.25 7.44        
4 Gävle  1    6.7                  7.82     7.77      8.02      8.19       7.79       7.97 6.99        
5 Gävle  1.25 6.52                 7.43     7.33      7.11      7.72       7.88       7.91 6.96        
6 Gävle  1.5  6.41                 7.25     7.28      6.92      7.63       7.01       7.64 6.7
```

The Mill column actually have 338 rows and several different sample names (Gävle, Obbola, Aspa etc). I use tis data set to make fawcet_wraped plots:

[image: Time_plots]

I would like to reshape this data set so that in the plots each panel is a Mill instead of a time_stamp with the Time stamp being the group plotted instead of Mill while keeping the x and y as is. In order to do this I have to reshape the data set, but the way I understand it I have both transpose and change from wide to long format, getting something like this:

```
Acid    Time        Gävle   Obbola  Munksund            
0       1_day       10.5    13      15.3
0.5     1_day       8.79    11.03   12.82
0.75    1_day       8.05    10.59   12.27
1       1_day       6.7     9.72    11.6
1.25    1_day       6.52    9.06    10.41
1.5     1_day       6.41    8.01    10.3
1.75    1_day       6.24    8.48    5.78
2       1_day       6.37    8.49    9.94
2.25    1_day       5.08    8.03    7.13
```

I tried using `melt` (from both reshape2 and data.table) but since the `patterns` call is not recognised by my version despite reloading both of the librarys I think I have to use `reshape`. I have looked at several other examples but none seems to have the transpose problem I have, and I can´t seem to figure it out by myself. Help please?

**Edit:**
As per request:
dput(Sample_pH): https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AfJWPL1GjzAskRKzXWr8MDEvlHBrY-SxjKDZ7LY7lNY/edit?usp=sharing

And the ggplot code I use for making the graphs:

```
ggplot(gather(Sample_pH, key=Time, value="value", -"Mill", -"Acid"),
          aes(x=Acid, y=as.numeric(value), colour=Mill, group=Mill) )  +
              geom_line() +
               scale_color_ucscgb() +
              facet_wrap(~ Time, scales = 'free', ncol =4) +
               ylab("pH") +
              xlab("ml 12.1 M HCl") +
              theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
                    legend.title = element_blank())
```

Comment: Could you make a reproducible example with `dput()` for your data and the ggplot2 code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach is to use the new pivot_londer and pivot_wider functions from the tidyr package.

Easier convention to use and has convenient text manipulation options built in. In this case removing the "X." that was added to column names.

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="Mill   Acid `1_day`  `3_days` `1_week` `2_weeks` `4_weeks` `2_months` `3_months` `6-7_months`
Gävle  0    10.5      12.0     10.9      10.7      10.6       10.1       10    9.81        
Gävle  0.5  8.79    10        9.29      9.08      9.39       9.13       9.14 8.86        
Gävle  0.75 8.05     8.95     8.33      8.26      8.24       8.22       8.25 7.44        
Gävle  1    6.7       7.82     7.77      8.02      8.19       7.79       7.97 6.99        
Gävle  1.25 6.52     7.43     7.33      7.11      7.72       7.88       7.91 6.96        
Gävle  1.5  6.41     7.25     7.28      6.92      7.63       7.01       7.64 6.7   
Obbola  0    10.5    12.0     10.9      10.7      10.6       10.1       10    9.81        
Obbola  0.5  8.79    10        9.29      9.08      9.39       9.13       9.14 8.86        
Obbola  0.75 8.05     8.95     8.33      8.26      8.24       8.22       8.25 7.44        
Obbola  1    6.7     7.82     7.77      8.02      8.19       7.79       7.97 6.99        
Obbola  1.25 6.52   7.43     7.33      7.11      7.72       7.88       7.91 6.96        
Obbola  1.5  6.41   7.25     7.28      6.92      7.63       7.01       7.64 6.7   ")

library(tidyr)

longdf <- df %>% pivot_longer(-c("Mill", "Acid"), names_to="Time", values_to = "value", names_prefix="X.")

answer <-longdf %>% pivot_wider(id_cols= c("Time", "Acid" ), names_from = "Mill" )
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked after I figured out a smaller snag. As I understand the code, the reason one first redo the df into a long format is to make the transformation easier as the long format is a good neutral way of datastacking but feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

As a reference for others: I originally did not notice that one of my numeric columns was not in fact a numeric column but a char. I did try ````values_ptype```` and ````values_transform```` but for some reason I did not work. The solution I went with was the more simple of just running Sample_pH[, -"Mill"] thru a sapply.

Comment: Glad this worked for you.  yes, correct the long format does provide a flexible form for the data. Sorry, that I didn't point out the non-numeric column, but I thought that was an artifact of coping the data into this question.